# ASP.NET Core ViewLocationExpander can not find view in other assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I have following solution:

```
src
   /Web
   /Web.Admin
        /Controller
          /TestControllr.cs
        /Views
            /Test
               /Index.cshtml
```

I use Application Part for separate My application parts:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var adminAssembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("Web.Admin"));

        services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(adminAssembly);

        services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
        {
           options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new AdminViewLocationExpander());

        });
    }
}
```

and create a ViewLocationExpander name of `AdminViewLocationExpander`:

```
public class AdminViewLocationExpander : IViewLocationExpander
{
    public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
    {
        const string adminAssembly = "Web.Admin";

        var adminViewsLocations = new []
        {
            $"/{adminAssembly}/Views/{{1}}/{{0}}.cshtml",
            $"/{adminAssembly}/Views/Shared/{{0}}.cshtml"
        };

        viewLocations = adminViewsLocations.Concat(viewLocations);

        return viewLocations;
    }
}
```

When I run the application with this URL `localhost:6046/Test/Index` get following:

```
 InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following 
 locations were searched:
 /Web.Admin/Views/Test/Index.cshtml
 /Web.Admin/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
 /Views/Test/Index.cshtml
 /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
```

How Can I Solve this?

Comment: Your project is named "App.Web.Admin" not "Web.Admin" so the `adminAssembly` variable should be set to `App.Web.Admin`, right?

Comment: @NickGeorge  no, I edit question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my projects I keep views as embedded resources in separate class library projects/assembly, packaged as nugets. For example [here is one project with embedded views](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe.SimpleContent/tree/master/src/cloudscribe.SimpleContent.Web.Views.Bootstrap3).

I don't need a custom IViewLocationExpander to find them. Instead I create an extension method like this:

```
public static RazorViewEngineOptions AddCloudscribeSimpleContentBootstrap3Views(this RazorViewEngineOptions options)
{
    options.FileProviders.Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(
                typeof(Bootstrap3).GetTypeInfo().Assembly,
                "cloudscribe.SimpleContent.Web.Views.Bootstrap3"
          ));

    return options;
}
```

then in startup of the main app I add them like this:

```
services.AddMvc()
.AddRazorOptions(options =>
{
    options.AddCloudscribeSimpleContentBootstrap3Views();


});
```

In my class library with embedded views I just have them in a Views folder as normal, and in my .csproj file I make them embedded resources like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
<EmbeddedResource Include="Views\**" Exclude="bin\**;obj\**;**\*.xproj;packages\**;@(EmbeddedResource)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

They work the same as if they were on disk, and if I want to override/customize a view I can copy it locally and the local view will be used instead of the embedded one automatically.

Comment: Are those embedded views taken into account by the Razor compilation task (tag `<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>` in the .csproj)?

Comment: No, I don't think so. But I think there is work going on for 2.1 release that will make it easier to have pre-compiled views in class libraries.