# Find ASP.NET Core 2 Razor Pages in another assembly

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

A few days ago I [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46380332/asp-net-core-viewlocationexpander-can-not-find-view-in-other-assembly) that how can I find **Views** in another assembly.

now I want use ASP.NET Core 2 Razor Pages so I want to locate those in another assembly.

I do use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46383880/6823285) for locating **Views** and this worked fine but this not worked for **Razor Pages** and I cant do this.

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Locate Razor Pages in another assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46670806/locate-razor-pages-in-another-assembly)