# AspNetCore include Razor Pages in other assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-routing, razor-pages

## Context

I have an integration test project in which I start a test version of my actual application server. I use a test startup that extends the startup of the actual app.

```
- MyApp.Web/
   |
   \ Pages/
      |
      \ Index.cshtml
      \ Index.cshtml.cs
   \ Startup.cs

- Tests/
   |
   \ MyApp.Tests.IntegrationTests/
      |
      \ TestStartup.cs // Extends Startup in MyApp project
      \ TestFixture.cs // Starts the test server using TestStartup.
```

## Question:

Because I'm running the test assembly, the Pages directory is not being found and so none of my routes are found. How do I tell TestStartup to include the Pages directory above?

## Extra

I looked a [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46670806/locate-razor-pages-in-another-assembly), but this seems way too convoluted. This guy has a lot of logic that seems like hacks. There must be a cleaner way to do this?

Also, I would prefer (although if it's not possible to fine) if there was a way to do it via namespace rather than directory too. Like if you could say, "Use all classes in the "MyApp.Pages" namespace," instead of, "Use all files in this directory." since directory names are subject to change on refactors and depending on where each developer puts them on their system (I put mine in ~/projects/ but someone else might put them in ~/WorkProjects. Not to mention Windows paths vs unix paths).